# Calling images in loop creates overlapping variables

Tags: javascript, image, function, loops, canvas

I'm trying to apply a function to each image on a page as it is loaded. The variables within my image.onload function seem to be global, which results in images getting skipped over and unexpected effects (such as images not respecting applied `width`s).

Here's my whole JS:

```
var imgList = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
$('img').after('<canvas></canvas>');

for (var j = 0; j < imgList.length; j++){
    var image = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[j];
    var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[j];

    image.onload = function(){
        console.log(canvas);
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        canvas.width = image.width;
        canvas.height = image.height;

        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        var pixelNum = imgData.data.length;

        //initialize brightness for levels
        var redMax = 0; 
        var redMin = 255;
        var greenMax = 0; 
        var greenMin = 255;
        var blueMax = 0; 
        var blueMin = 255;

        for(var i = 0; i < pixelNum; i += 4){
            //set min and max values for each color
            if (imgData.data[i] > redMax) { redMax = imgData.data[i] };
            if (imgData.data[i] < redMin) { redMin = imgData.data[i] };
            if (imgData.data[i+1] > greenMax) { greenMax = imgData.data[i+1] };
            if (imgData.data[i+1] < greenMin) { greenMin = imgData.data[i+1] };
            if (imgData.data[i+2] > blueMax) { blueMax = imgData.data[i+2] };
            if (imgData.data[i+2] < blueMin) { blueMin = imgData.data[i+2] };
        }
        console.log(redMin+" "+redMax+" "+blueMin+" "+blueMax+" "+greenMin+" "+greenMax);

        for(var i = 0; i < pixelNum; i += 4){
            //map colors to 0 - 255 range
            imgData.data[i] = (imgData.data[i] - redMin) * (255 / (redMax - redMin));
            imgData.data[i+1] = (imgData.data[i+1] - greenMin) * (255 / (greenMax - greenMin));
            imgData.data[i+2] = (imgData.data[i+2] - blueMin) * (255 / (blueMax - blueMin));
        }
        ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);

        //remove original img tag
        $(image).remove();
        console.log(image);

     };
};
```

And here's my console output (with commentary below):

```
<canvas> (line 20)
0 0 0 0 0 0 (line 47)
<img src="images/cimg1836.jpg"> (line 59)

<canvas width="400" height="268"> (line 20)
29 255 18 255 23 255 (line 47)
<img src="images/cimg1836.jpg"> (line 59)
```

-canvas tag gets added as expected. 
-brightness max and min should not both be zero, since min is set to 255 and max to 0 (the image is being read as entirely black pixels). 
-the image listed is the second of two images in markup.

-the first canvas tag is being output to console–the second canvas ignores the `img{ width:400px; }` style, which should be inherited from the `img`.
-as expected.
-as expected.

How can I keep the images distinct, that is to say, keep them running all of the code and only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript does not have block scope, so those variables in your loop are indeed "global".

I'd move the entire loop body into a function that takes `j` as an argument. By doing so, `image` and `canvas` will be unique to the scope of each individual function call, and will therefore not "overlap" and cause the effects you've seen.

```
function doMyThing(image_n) {
   var image    = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[image_n];
   var canvas   = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[image_n];

   image.onload = function() { /* ... */ };
}

for (var j = 0; j < imgList.length; j++) {
   doMyThing(j);
}
```

The need for such hacks (that is, introducing function scopes where you wouldn't necessarily intuit them) is a peculiarity of JavaScript, and you ought to keep it in the back of your mind as you continue programming in this language.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I previously tried creating a function and calling it in a loop, but somehow didn't get calling j as an argument. You saved my sanity.